# Dynamically set href anchor tags not sending a get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, href

I'm not really sure where I"m screwing up with this. Basically I'm reading from my database to generate an html page and dynamically set the hrefs of some anchor tags. When I click on the links, however, the page just reloads and doesn't send a GET request to the server. The important part of the Jade rendering is here.

```
each val in tournaments

      a(href="/home/tournaments/?_id=" + val._id)
```

The _id param is just the default _id MongoDB gives to the document upon creation.

I'm also using Express to handle my server side requests. The pertinent one for this is here:

```
app.route("/home/tournaments/:id")
        .get(function(req, res, next) {
            console.log("Request: " + req.query._id);
        });
```

Nothing gets printed to the console when I click the anchor tag, so I guess it's not reaching this route for some reason.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the `href` property when you inspect the resulting `html` page?

Comment: Here's what the chrome inspector is giving me:

`<a href="/home/tournaments/?_id=5647b1487b4f8fb02131e7a8"     class="btn btn-sm btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-pencil no-border-radius"></a> `

That's the correct Id for sure, that I know. Is the format of the url correct?

Comment: Looks good. Do you actually need the ":id" part in `app.route("/home/tournaments/:id")`, as there is nothing there in the `url`? Could you try without ":id"?

Comment: I was actually already using "home/tournaments" for a different route, but per your approach I just made a new route "home/tournaments/edit" and appended the parameters to the end of that route instead. That ended up working! 

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're placing the ID in the query string instead of the actual url path. So to make your existing route match, you'd need to instead do this:

```
each val in tournaments
  a(href="/home/tournaments/" + val._id)
```

and then use `req.params.id` instead of `req.query._id`.

*OR* you could adjust your route pattern to just be `/home/tournaments`.